# Is there something like the .NET Dictionary with duplicated keys to fill with a text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a text file with the following structure

```
01|value|value|value|value|value|value
02|value|value|value|value|value|value
03A|value|value|value|value|value|value
03A|value|value|value|value|value|value
.
.
N
04|value|value|value|value|value|value
05|value|value|value|value|value|value
06|value|value|value|value|value|value
.
.
N (variable lines)
```

I tried to read the text file and add it to a dictionary of type `<string, string[]>` in order to use it like `MyDic["01"][0]`, this is a fragment of the code:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> txtFromFile= new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
string strLine;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
   while ((strLine= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      string[] strNodes= strLine.Split('|');
      txtFromFile.Add(strNodes[0], strNodes);
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, this text file could have duplicated keys like `03A`, so I was wondering if there's a collection in c# to achieve this.

**NOTE**  I saw a class named lookup, but there's no constructor for it.

1. Any thoughts my friends?
2. What do you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) extension method:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
ILookup<string, string[]> result = lines
    .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
    .ToLookup(parts => parts[0]);
```

Comment: That doesn't quite fit the need, since he's wanting the return from the lookup to be the split string, which would be the value of line.Split('|'), but it's close and I'm being nitpicky.

Comment: If you have .NET 4, use `ReadLines()` (which returns `IEnumerable<string>`) instead of `ReadAllLines()` which loads the entire file into an array you don't need.

Comment: @d_r_w that's what this does - `result` has type `ILookup<string, string[]>`.

Comment: @dahlbyk D'oh! You're right. The use of the same term for the two lambdas tripped my brain.

Comment: @d_r_w: I have renamed the variable to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a class like

```
public class MyLine
{
  string key { get;set;}
  string[] value {get;set;}
}
```

and store it in a geneirc List

then you can use linq to query whatever you want ...

Comment: That comes with a major performance hit compared to a Dictionary, which is O(1), and the best case for a List is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>` or `List<Tuple<string, string[]>>`

(And of course you might prefer a different collection type instead of `List<>`)

Comment: +1 Except maybe he would want: `List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>`

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you are trying to use the wrong type, if you are concerned with multiple entries with the same key. You can achieve this with a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>` and your own lookup function, likely through extending the class, or you can add another dictionary inside the dictionary as your value type: `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string[]>>`. The Dictionary option is the better bet as it has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

How about a List with a custom type?

```
class KeyValue 
{ 
 String ID { get ; set ; } 
 List<String> Values { get ; private set ;}
 (..Constructor etc...)
}

List<KeyValue> myValues = new List<KeyValue>();
while ((strLine= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
 string[] strNodes= strLine.Split('|');
 myValues.Add(new KeyValue(strNodes[0],strNodes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to distinguish between values on the first `03A` line from values on the second `03A` line, but I think you're looking for a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx). `NameValueCollections` allow you to add multiple values to the same key, and the `Add()` method should check for pre-existing keys before appending the values/creating a new key/value entry.

There's a good example of the way to use the NameValueCollection at the bottom of that MSDN reference article, so you should be able to use that to determine if it's what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought would be to use

```
Dictionary<string, List<string[]>>
```

Where "string" is the value that might be repeated. When it gets repeated, you create another Dictionary inside. If a row exists once, it will have one List. If a duplicate row is found, add another. In this way, you can see how many duplicate rows there were just by count of Lists.